# Is there any port forwarding I need to do when hosting a server locally for Android app use?

Tags: android, localhost, ports

So I wanted to test my app on an actual android device. I've debugged it on the virtual device and it's working smoothly, but I want it to be able to work on actual phones now for debugging and whatnot as well. I changed the IP I use to access a locally hosted server from 10.0.2.2 to my own. So every time I call up the server which my app queries, it went from:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/pagemyappwants.php");
```

to

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://76.blahblah.etc/pagemyappwants.php");
```

the latter being my own computer's IP, which I have used to run remotely accessed servers in the past. I've tested this for the wamp/apache server I'm running, and using this IP you can access the php pages from other computers. However, when I try to use my app, the app freezes up for a few minutes, then moves on as if the task was completed, but when checking the mysql db which would log a change/addition made via the app, nothing has happened.

So in summary, is there any port forwarding I need to do in order for a locally hosted server for android use to work? Or anything else, for that matter, which would fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description doesn't seem very clear, but if I understand correctly that your application is making an HTTP call over the public net to your own PC, via your public IP address, then the only port that needs opening is port 80 (assuming non-secure HTTP).

You say "the app freezes up for a few minutes, then moves on as if the task was completed". Do you actually mean minutes, or just a lot of seconds? If minutes, that doesn't sound right as the HTTP timeout is not that long.

If it were me I'd want to:

- Get some tracing/debugging going on the HTTP call to see EXACTLY what is happening, and particularly what exception is being thrown, or what result is coming back. It sounds like it's timing out, but you're not mentioning an exception, which leads me to think your app is now handling exceptions correctly.
- I'd try accessing the HTTP URL using the browser on the device, to see if it actually has access to it.
- Check the port forward. It's not usual for routers to be configured by default to handle incoming HTTP requests as it creates security risks. If you have previously set that up, and it is now not working, is it possible that the port forward from the router to your PC is failing as your PC has a different IP address?

Comment: I'll try it again and check logcat for the exact exception being thrown. I'll also open up port 80. Will I need to change the IP call to something like 'http://myip:80/page.php'?

Comment: The :80 is redundant as it's the default port. You only need to add that if you aren't using the default port on your web server. So http:76.x.x.x/page.php will work fine.

Comment: Nothing is appearing in logcat during the time the app is hung up on a request, waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Ok yea, I get an IO exception, operation timed out. Port 80 is open like I said. The time it took to get that timeout is roughly 3 minutes by the log's count. Any ideas where I should go from here?

Comment: Also, my phone's web browser cannot access it... This is weird, my other computer can access it fine, and my apache is definitely running.

Comment: I'd use another application on your phone to connect to port 80, e.g. your device browser. If that works, then something strange is happening, so I'd want to get HTTP logging going on both the device, and the server. Another option is to send the request to another server, and see if the request is received (i.e. determine if the problem is your router/server, or the Android app/device). You need more information to deduce the cause.

Comment: If your "other computer" is on the same internal network, the router may handle the traffic differently and successfully route it (less need for security if it knows the request is from inside the network). It looks to me that your router is not correctly forwarding port 80 traffic to your web server (or the firewall is blocking it). I don't see anything to suggest the Android device or app are at fault, everything points to a networking issue with the configuration of your router.

Comment: Would appreciate it if you'd mark my answer up, and select my answer  (i.e. click the tick). If you select the best answer for each question you ask, your score goes up, and people are more likely to answer your questions in future.

Comment: Strange, just the other day I could access my server stuff from other computers, now I can't. I'm sure that's the problem. Now to figure out why wamp/apache is only letting me access stuff locally...